# GWT CellTable - set column width

Tags: gwt, width, cell

Is it possible to set the column width of `CellTable` in GWT?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

EDIT:  As of GWT 2.2 table.setWidth and table.setColumnWidth are supported

```
table.setWidth("100%", true);
table.setColumnWidth(nameColumn, 35.0, Unit.PCT);
table.setColumnWidth(addressColumn, 65.0, Unit.PCT);
```

I was able to extend the CellTable with a method that sets the widths programmatically.  It's a bit of a hack since all the real methods that should do this are private to CellTable and it seems like GWT should provide this method directly, but it seems to work.

```
public void setColumnWidths(List<Integer> widths)
{
    TableElement tel = TableElement.as(getElement());
    NodeList<Element> colgroups = tel.getElementsByTagName("colgroup");
    if (colgroups.getLength() == 1)
    {
       TableColElement cge = TableColElement.as(colgroups.getItem(0));
       NodeList<Element> cols = cge.getElementsByTagName("col");
       for (int j = 0; j < widths.size(); j++)
       {
           TableColElement column = null;
           if (cols.getLength() > j)
           {
               column = TableColElement.as(cols.getItem(j));
           }
           else
           {
               column = cge.appendChild(Document.get().createColElement());
           }

           column.setWidth(widths.get(j)+"px");

       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a stylename for the specific column, using the `addColumnStyleName(int index, java.lang.String styleName)` method.

[Javadoc for CellTable](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/google/gwt/gwt-dev/2.1.0/gwt-dev-2.1.0-javadoc.jar!/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html)

Comment: I know about this method by don't know how to use it. Where such style class should be declared?

Comment: In your application's stylesheet. Have a look at [ClientBundle](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) or just include a custom stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I would like to to declare this stylesheet in a CellTable.Resource but I get an Exception: [ERROR] Unable to process CSS. Do You know how it can be done?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done this myself, yet, and your info about the error is a little too vague.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is adding a new class in my css. This class gets applied only to select elements whose length varies depending on data.

```
.__gwt_cell select{
    width:170px;
}
```

Then applying it on my particular cell style like o:

```
table.getColumn(3).setCellStyleNames("yourstyle");
```

Answer (score -3):

The GWT documentation for CellTable covers this, see:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html

Under "Controlling Column Widths".