# GWT CellTable#setColumnWidth() not work when there is long text in cell

Tags: gwt, gwt-celltable

From [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461749/gwt-celltable-set-column-width) the author suggested:

```
table.setWidth("100%", true);
table.setColumnWidth(nameColumn, 35.0, Unit.PCT);
table.setColumnWidth(addressColumn, 65.0, Unit.PCT);
```

for CellTable column width to work, however in my project the `nameColumn` contain an extra long text, then this column will occupy almost all browser view, apparently the column width does not work, Could anybody shed some light on this?

The `nameColumn` defined as below:

```
        TextColumn<Person> nameColumn = new TextColumn<Person>()
        {

            @Override
            public String getValue( Person object )
            {
                return object.getUserName();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following method to set custom style on the column cell:

```
nameColumn.setCellStyleNames("name-cell");
```

The following structure is generated(in `DOM`) for the cell:

```
<td class="xxxxxxxx xxxxxx name-cell">
   <div style="outline:none;">Very long name ...</div>
</td>
```

So you have to define following `css` classes to set the wanted style and limit the cell and text size:

```
.name-cell {
...
}

.name-cell div {
...
}
```

**Update**

I tested the method `table.setColumnWidth(` and works well for me.
Here is how I do it:

- Table constructed by UI binder
- Create columns
- Set table width
- add columns to the table
- set column width (with `table.setColumnWidth` )

When you calculate the cell width don't forget to take padding into account.

*Used GWT 2.4*

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your way works, but do you know why the method: table.setColumnWidth(nameColumn, 35.0, Unit.PCT); does not work?

Comment: Thank you! Your steps are correct but one more thing, we have to  set table.setWidth("100%", true); first to put the table in fixed width mode. see here: [link](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable#columnWidths)